# How do I check users inside my openstack project using openstack.cloud ansible collection?

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, openstack

I want to check users inside my openstack project using Ansible Collection.

I want to check user list, user role in specific project look like this.

```
(RPtest-rpaap) [stack@director-vm 00-rcfile]$ openstack role assignment list --project test --project-domain default --names --effective 
+--------+---------------+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+-----------+
| Role   | User          | Group | Project               | Domain | System | Inherited |
+--------+---------------+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+-----------+
| member | rpadm@Default |       | test@Default |        |        | False     |
| admin  | rpadm@Default |       | test@Default |        |        | False     |
| member | rpadm@Default |       | test@Default |        |        | False     |
| reader | rpadm@Default |       | test@Default |        |        | False     |
+--------+---------------+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

But I couldn't find a way when I looked up the Openstack.cloud Ansible Collection document.

I check many module(Items below), but i can't find that.

module_ex.)
identity_role module – Manage a OpenStack identity (Keystone) role

identity_role_info module – Fetch OpenStack identity (Keystone) roles

identity_user module – Manage a OpenStack identity (Keystone) user

identity_user_info module – Fetch OpenStack identity (Keystone) users

role_assignment module – Assign OpenStack identity groups and users to roles

project_info module – Retrieve information about one or more OpenStack projects

How can I check the account information of a specific project as shown in the table above using openstack.cloud collection??

Thanks